# Complicated multiple cases for switch statements

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

In my program I ask the user to enter in the size of an array, then fill the array with numbers entered by the user.

Then the user enters in a number which will check to see if it exists in the array. If it does, it will print a message to the console.

I want to be able to print different messages depending on the position of the number in the array.

If it's the 1st, 21st, 31st, etc... a different message will be printed

If it's the 2nd, 22nd, 32nd, etc... a different message will be printed

If it's the 3rd, 23rd, 33rd, etc... a different message will be printed

Then the default case is if it's one of the "th" numbers, a different message will be printed

Here is a segment of my code, it only works for the first 10 numbers. The problem I have is that 11th, 12th, 13th do not follow normal rules, as for any number that ends in 11, 12 or 13.

```
Console.Write("Now enter a number to compare: ");
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int pos = Array.IndexOf(arr, c);

if (pos > -1)
{
    switch (pos)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}st number in this list", c, pos + 1);
            break;

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}nd number in this list", c, pos + 1);
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}rd number in this list", c, pos + 1);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}th number in this list", c, pos + 1);
            break;
    }

}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry this number does not appear in the array");
}
```

I'd rather not enter it manually as eventually I will be using large sized arrays.

I want to either be able to use a wildcard (*) or a comma, but it won't let me. What's an easier way to solve this problem without entering every single number manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change `switch (pos)` to `switch(pos % 10)` and adjust your switch statement:

```
switch (pos % 10)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}st number in this list", c, pos);
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}nd number in this list", c, pos);
        break;

    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}rd number in this list", c, pos);
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is the {1}th number in this list", c, pos);
        break;
}
```

The [modulo operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) `%` will give you the remainder of the integer division `pos / 10` -- that is, an integer always in the range `[0, 9]`. This is enough help to make the rest of your code almost work, except for the special cases 11, 12 and 13.

To handle these cases without messing with the `switch` cases themselves, you can expand the solution to

```
var position = (pos == 11 || pos == 12 || pos == 13) ? 999 : pos % 10;
switch (position)
{
    ...
}
```

The number 999 above is a completely arbitrary choice that is required to fall into the `default` case of the `switch`. I used 999 here to eliminate the possibility of miscommunication; you can select another number if you prefer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: So true, I missed that. Updated to address that case.

Answer (score 3):

Use a modulo operator (number % 10).